# Encoding for special characters not working in email subject for sendgrid templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates, sendgrid-ruby

I have been using the sendgrid-ruby gem for sending emails. The subject of the email doesn't decode special characters properly.
Eg. Sending this subject for the email `How's it going` translates to this in the actual email `How&apos;s it going`

I have tried encoding the string for subject to different formats such as ASCII, ISO_8859_1 but none of this works.

```
@body_json['personalizations'][0]['dynamic_template_data'] = {
    'email_title': @email_title,
    'content': @description,
    'subject': "How's it going"
}

SendGrid::API.new(api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']).client.mail._('send').post(request_body: @body_json)
```

The subject for email should show special characters correctly such as ' & :

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should be using triple brackets in your subject section i.e. `{{{subject}}}` for subjects with special characters.
If you use the double brackets approach your string is going to be HTML encoded.

Check this link from SendGrid repository https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/741#issuecomment-422026634

Comment: If you could notify that my answer is the correct one I would be happy :)

Comment: Using `{{{` (triple brackets) will prevent the HTML escaping of variables, which could eventually cause HTML injection security concern. Is there any other way to fix the above issue?

Comment: hey @ArvindKalra
i think securing what is going to be rendered on that place is our responsibility, so I would try to previously evaluate the contents of what is going to be rendered there

Answer (score 2):

Okay so after chatting with sendgrid support I was able to figure this out. The issue is not with the sendgrid request from my side. Whenever making a template always be sure that subject title in header is inside double brackets i.e. `{{subject}}`. This will ensure that all special characters work inside this block.

Comment: With double brackets, you won't get a special character to sanitize. You need to use the triple brackets approach. The correct answer is the one below